# How to create protected docker volume

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I have a host machine on which I need to run multiple container. Each container belongs to a different user and the users have ssh access to the host machine.

Each container needs a volume and the data within the volume should be protected for users, that is if container C1 belongs to user U1, other users should not see the content of volume for C1. If I create a volume using `docker volume create` it mounts the volume directory to the default location on the host machine (e.g. /var/lib/docker/volumes/...) which is accessible by all the users. How can I create a volume which is accessible to designated users only. Can I change the mount directory on the host machine to the home directory of each user? If so, can the containers still access the content of the volume as it's protected?

Comment: First rule of Docker security: anyone who can run any `docker` command has unrestricted root-level access over the entire system.  There's no such thing as a user-specific container or volume.

Comment: usrs won't have access to run any docker commands, but they can ssh into the host machine and see the content of the volume directories!

Comment: `/var/lib/docker` is not normally world-readable.  (In the Docker for Mac VM, it's mode 0744 owned by root.)

Comment: In terms of being able to just put the mounted data inside a user's home directory, a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) for each user could probably do this for you.